# how to return two httpresponse in the same function

Tags: django

I need to return two response, let's call A response and B response, during the same triggering condition. I try to write a pseudo code to explain my question.

```
def trigger_condition(request):
    return A_response, B_response
```

or

```
def trigger_condition(request):
    return A_response, then callback another_function

def another_function(request):
    return B_response
```

Comment: You can use HttpResponseRedirect to redirect your response to a different view.

Comment: @VipinGupta but how can i return one response and then redirect to different view.?

Comment: You can't. Returning an HttpResponse will send the response back to the browser. You can probably have an ajax call, so when the first view returns a response, send another request in the ajax success.

Comment: You can't send two responses for 1 request. That is not how HTTP protocol works. I'm sure your problem can be solved in another way. If you'll add more info on why you want to send two responses, maybe someone can help you out.